# How to center a spinner in actionbar from fragment

Tags: android-actionbar, spinner, android

Well, how to add a spinner in the center of the actionbar from fragment?

I've already done this:

ActionBar menu file: R.menu.tabmap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_map_spinner"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_spinner">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_map_more"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"        
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"
        android:title="@string/action_map_more"/>

</menu>
```

ActionBar spinner file: R.layout.actionbar_spinner

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_spinner_change_map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the (Sherlock)Fragment, I did this:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.tabmap, menu);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.action_map_spinner).getActionView()
                                .findViewById(R.id.actionbar_spinner_change_map);

    spinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

However, the spinner is not in center, Any idea?
[image: Spinner not in center]

Answer (score 0):

This is because your second item in the ActionBar, which is actionMapMore, also consumes part of the action bar. You should put the second item of the menu in your custom layout, and manipulate it correctly via `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to implement a custom view for your ActionBar. You can display virtually anything with your custom view not only a spinner. The downside is that you need to handle the add/remove menu items in the ActionBar yourself.

If you have a better solution, I would love to hear.